# Bukkit / Spigot - EntityDamageByEntityEvent : cast the shooter

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, eventhandler

I am creating a PvP plugin, but I cannot continue because I have a annoying cast problem that I cannot solve. I am trying to get the **last damage cause**, the **damager**, check if the damager used a **Arrow**, convert the 'arrow' into the **shooter**. But it constantly gives me errors in my console.

So here is my code

```
Player player = (Player)event.getPlayer(); // this variable is in my public void onPlayerMovement event
if(((EntityDamageByEntityEvent) player.getLastDamageCause()).getDamager() instanceof Arrow) 
{
   Arrow arrow = (Arrow) ((EntityDamageByEntityEvent) player.getLastDamageCause()).getDamager();
   ProjectileSource shooter = ((ProjectileSource) ((EntityDamageByEntityEvent) player.getLastDamageCause()).getDamager());

   if(shooter instanceof Player) // checking if the shooter is a player.
   {
      shooter.sendMessage("You hitted someone with a bow right?");
      player.sendMessage("You got hit by a bow..");
   }
}
```

The reason why I want to convert the arrow into the shooter is because I want to display a message to the shooter, and couple of other things.

This is the error

```
[22:39:10 ERROR]: Could not pass event PlayerMoveEvent to FendykPVP v1.8
    org.bukkit.event.EventException
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:310) ~[spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62) ~[spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:502) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:487) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:270) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PacketPlayInFlying.a(SourceFile:126) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PacketPlayInFlying$PacketPlayInPosition.a(SourceFile:57) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.PlayerConnectionUtils$1.run(SourceFile:13) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_121]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.SystemUtils.a(SourceFile:44) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.B(MinecraftServer.java:715) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.DedicatedServer.B(DedicatedServer.java:374) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.A(MinecraftServer.java:654) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:557) [spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.entity.CraftArrow cannot be cast to org.bukkit.entity.Player
    at GameCore.playerKill.onPlayerMovement(playerKill.java:102) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1391.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:306) ~[spigot-1.8.8.jar:git-Spigot-21fe707-e1ebe52]
    ... 15 more
```

I hope someone can help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not work, haven't tested it myself. But you need to check if it's an arrow before casting it. Also to get the shooter there is the method `arrow.getShooter()` in the projectile class which can be used by the arrow.

```
if(((EntityDamageByEntityEvent) player.getLastDamageCause()).getDamager() instanceof Arrow) {
    Arrow arrow = (Arrow) ((EntityDamageByEntityEvent) player.getLastDamageCause()).getDamager();
    ProjectileSource shooter = arrow.getShooter();

       if(shooter instanceof Player) // checking if the shooter is a player.
       {
          Player shooterPlayer = (Player) shooter;
          shooterPlayer.sendMessage("You hitted someone with a bow right?");
          player.sendMessage("You got hit by a bow..");
       }
}
```

If it does not help, please let me know what line 102 is.

Comment: Line 102: Player damager = (Player) entitydamager;

Comment: This Line is called when the player's Y <= 10

Comment: I added ProjectileSource shooter = arrow.getShooter(); but It gives me an error when I try to use this: shooter.sendmessage();. Its says:"the method sendMessage(String) is undefined for the type ProjectileSource".

Comment: Ok thank you. So I read the topic, I currently use Spigot. But what are the alternatives? Should I use NMS instead? Sorry I know what Spigot is but I exctually never heard about NMS.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, I will try the code when I get home

Answer (score 1):

The following is an excerpt of a tested solution to notify players when they shoot each other. This should help you along.

```
@EventHandler
public void onEntityDamageByEntity( EntityDamageByEntityEvent evt ) {
    // Is target a player, if not stop
    if ( !(evt.getEntity() instanceof Player) )
        return;

    Player damagee = (Player) evt.getEntity();

    // Is damager an arrow, if not stop
    if ( !(evt.getDamager() instanceof Arrow) )
        return;

    // Is shooter a player, if not stop
    ProjectileSource src = ((Arrow) evt.getDamager()).getShooter();
    if ( !(src instanceof Player) )
        return;

    Player damager = (Player) src;
    damager.sendMessage( "You just shot " + damagee.getName() );
    damagee.sendMessage( "You were shot by " + damager.getName() );
}
```